# How to match a phrase in elastic-search with expandable prefix and suffix?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-5

We have a use case in which we want to match phrases in elastic-search,  but in addition to phrase query we also want to search partial phrases.

Example:

Search phrase: "welcome you" or "lcome you" or "welcome yo" or "lcome yo" this should match to documents containing phrases:

"welcome you"

"we welcome you"

"welcome you to"

"we welcome you to"

i.e. we want to maintain the ordering of words by doing a phrase query with added functionality that is returns us results which contains phrase as a partial substring and with prefix and suffix expandable to certain configurable length.
In elastic I found something similar '[match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/blog/starts-with-phrase-matching)' but it only match phrases which starts with a particular prefix.

Ex return results starting with d prefix:

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/startswith/test/_search?pretty -d '{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "title": {
                "query": "d",
                "max_expansions": 5
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Is there any way that I could achieve this for suffix as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly encourage you to look into the [`shingle` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html).

You can define an index with a custom analyzer that leverages shingles in order to index a set of subsequent tokens together in addition to the tokens themselves.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/startswith -d '{
  "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_shingles": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "shingles"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "shingles": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 2,
            "output_unigrams": true
          }
        }
      }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_shingles"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

For instance, `we welcome you to` would be indexed as the following tokens

- `we`
- `we welcome`
- `welcome`
- `welcome you`
- `you`
- `you to`
- `to`

Then you can index a few sample documents:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/startswith/test/_bulk -d '
{"index": {}}
{"title": "welcome you"}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "we welcome you"}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "welcome you to"}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "we welcome you to"}
'
```

Finally, you can run the following query to match all four documents above, like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/startswith/test/_search -d '{
   "query": {
       "match": {"title": "welcome you"}
   }
}'
```

Note that this approach is more powerful than the `match_phrase_prefix` query, because it allows you to match subsequent tokens anywhere in your body of text, whether at the beginning or the end.

Comment: But this solution won't handle cases when I search for something like "lcome you" because it won't find any token "lcome" which is a partial string of "welcome".

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear that you also wanted partial matches. You can try to improve the solution by using the `ngram` token filter as a replacement of the shingle one or as a complement to it and that will work out.