# Elasticsearch - parts of string with correct word arrangement

Tags: elasticsearch, match, elastic-stack

I'm wondering how to properly query this scenario:

Field values:

1. 20182199
2. 20182188
3. 20182177

Query-strings (that should match all three):

- 2018 -> hit
- 0182 -> fail
- 821 -> fail

The other *requirement* is, that if greater than 1 word is present in the query string, both (the whole query string) must match, not every word of the string seperately.

Thats why I choosed a **match phrase prefix** query.  (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html). It only doesn't cover hits on inner elements of a word. That's what I am now looking for :-)

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't understand `it doesn't cover hits on inner elements of a word. ` part, can u explain it with some example.

Comment: I mean: value "20182188" is hit by query value "2018". But I don't get hits with "0182".

Comment: Btw: This is a related question and exactly what I need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757857/how-to-match-a-phrase-in-elastic-search-with-expandable-prefix-and-suffix/54950694#54950694

Answer (score 0):

I believe Elasticsearch docs specifically cover your use case and you are looking to match what Elasticsearch refers to as ngrams.

- [Partial Matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html) - a quick introduction
- [Ngrams for Partial Matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html) - it's worth noting that Elasticsearch search calls sequence of characters ngrams, and sequence of tokens shingles (a slight difference from what you may be used to)
- [Wildcard and Regexp Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html) - the same section on partial matching has notes on these queries that might suffice for you and may not require you to reindex/change analysis